# Complex analysis, showing a function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega$ be the right half plane excluding the imgainary axis and $f\in H(\Omega)$ such that $|f(z)|<1$ for all $z\in\Omega$. If there exists $\alpha\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log|f(re^{i\alpha})|}{r}=-\infty$$ prove that $f=0$.

The hint is define $g_n(z)=f(z)e^{nz}$, then by previous exericise $|g_n|<1$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Comment: Not that I know how to solve this, but what does $H(\Omega)$ stands for?

Comment: holomorphic function on omega

Comment: It would probably help to know what the "previous exercise" is.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy That's an outline for the proof of [Phragmen-Lindelöf's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta $ be a positive real number and $\tilde{f}(z)=f(z+\delta e^{i\alpha })$.  It is easy to see that
$\tilde{f}(z)\in H(\Pi)$, $|\tilde{f}(z)|<1$  and
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log|\tilde{f}(re^{i\alpha})|}{r}=-\infty.
$$
Of course  $\tilde{f}(z) \in C(\bar\Pi)$.
Therefore Eclipse Sun's argument may apply to $\tilde{g}_n(z)=\tilde{f}(z)e^{nz}$ and we have $\tilde{f}=0$, which implies $f(z)=0$ for $\operatorname{Re}\, z>\delta $. Since we can take  $\delta>0$  arbitrarily (or by the coincidence theorem) we see $f=0$ for all $z\in \Pi$.

Comment: That's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give a partial proof.

Let $g_n(z)=f(z)e^{nz}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, and $g_n(z)\in H(\Pi)$.

**Assume $g_n(z)\in C(\bar\Pi)$.**

Let $K_1=\{re^{i\theta}\mid\theta\in(\alpha,\pi/2)\}$, $K_2=\{re^{i\theta}\mid-\theta\in(\alpha,\pi/2)\}$ and $K_3=\Pi\setminus(K_1\cup K_2)$. By the assumption $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log|f(re^{i\alpha})|}{r}=-\infty$, $g_n(z)$ is bounded on each sector $K_i$. Since $g_n(z)$ doesn't grow too fast, by Phragmen-Lindelöf's principle for sectors, $g_n(z)$ is bounded in $\Pi$.

By Phragmen-Lindelöf's principle again, this time for the right half plane, $|g_n(z)|\le1$. Since it is true for all $n$, we must have $f=0$.

It remains to show that the assumption $g_n(z)\in C(\bar\Pi)$ is true, or it is redundant.